# Game Center ‘Real-Time Match’ rejected by App Store Review as they can’t connect

Tags: game-center, appstore-approval, real-time-multiplayer

I have made a ‘Real Time Match’ where players connect via the matchmaker interface provided by Apple’s Game Center.

Before you play the game, you obviously need to connect to another player either by randomly being assigned to a player or by inviting a friend via Game Center.

Apple keep rejecting my metadata as they can’t test the functionality of the game because they can’t get past the Matchmaker screen (I.e. there is no-one they can play). In the screenshots they have sent me they have tapped ‘play now’ to randomly connect, but obviously (as the game is not live) they don’t connect to anyone!

I have sent them a video of it running between two of my devices and explained the issue, but they still reject it as they can’t test the game.

They still are requiring a username and password to login and play, which I can’t provide as the connection is handled by Game Center and a users AppleID.

Am I being short sighted here? How can you get a real-time match through review if they reject it as they have no one to play?